# filtering resources in separate execution of maven war plugin

Tags: maven-war-plugin

Is it possible to filter resources - each in separate execution tag?
My goal is to have 2 war files each with resources filtered using different filter file.
Actually this solution is not working - variables have no values, are untouched like 
`<jta-data-source>${ds-jta}</jta-data-source>`
- I have to add filters and resources tag outside maven-war-plugin - commented section.
I thought it is possible to specify this "filterting" in execution configration - as shown in snippet.

```
<build>
<!-- I dont want to add this here - I want to have it in execution
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <filters>
        <filter>config/1.properties</filter>
    </filters> -->
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>1</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
               <filters>
                  <filter>config/1.properties</filter>
               </filters>
               <classifier>-1</classifier>
               <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-1</webappDirectory>
               <webResources>
                  <resource>
                     <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                     <filtering>true</filtering>
                  </resource>
               </webResources>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
               <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
         <execution>
            <id>2</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
               <filters>
                  <filter>config/2.properties</filter>
               </filters>
               <classifier>-2</classifier>
               <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-2</webappDirectory>
               <webResources>
                  <resource>
                     <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                     <filtering>true</filtering>
                  </resource>
               </webResources>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
               <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Any clues what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The .war created by maven-war-plugin looks like:

```
  ├── myapp.war
    │   ├── index.html    │   
    │   ├── myapp.properties
    │   ├── logback.xml
    │   ├── META-INF   
    │   │   ├── persistence.xml    
    │   │   
    │   └── WEB-INF          
    │       ├── classes   
    │       │   ├── myapp.properties
    │       │   ├── logback.xml
    │       │   ├── META-INF   
    │       │   │   ├── persistence.xml
```

I wanted to filter 'ds-server-jta' variable in tag `<jta-data-source>${ds-server-jta}</jta-data-source>` that was defined in persistence.xml. Maven-war-plugin filtered only persistence.xml located in META-INF.
Concerning the fact that maven-war-plugin created this .war with both META-INFs and only one persistence.xml was filtered (the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml one) I added to plugin configuration the following:

```
 <webResources>
     <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
         <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
    </resource>
    <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
 </webResources>
```

This tells the plugin explicitly which resources to filter and now both files are changed as it was required.

Persistence.xml in META-INF is however not used by my application server (Glassfish) but maven-war-plugin creates it anyway. The one that is used by the server is the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml.
Now I am trying not to create the first, unused by appserver META-INF catalogue in my .war but its just a small detail.